# Quickest way to add a single column of data to other columns for given indexes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a program that needs to add the value of one column to multiple other columns and I was surprised to find out that doing the calculation across all of the columns at once was much slower then doing it column by column in a loop with pandas.

I was hoping something could tell me the fastest method to do what I need to do and also explain why the time on line 10 is so much faster then in line 11.

Thanks

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: df_1 = pd.DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(10000000, 4)), columns=['a','b','c', 'd'])

In [5]: sample_ind = range(1, 100)

In [6]: copy_columns = ['a', 'b']

In [7]: df_1.head()
Out[7]: 
          a         b         c         d
0  1.147683  1.008620  0.287466  0.766438
1  1.123729  0.373583  0.298866  1.187121
2  1.773574  0.120433  0.363052  0.269104
3  1.717708  0.330670  1.015575  1.390325
4  0.841748  0.181788  0.219881  0.267149

In [8]: df_1['new'] = df_1['c'] + df_1['d']

In [9]: df_1.head()
Out[9]: 
          a         b         c         d       new
0  1.147683  1.008620  0.287466  0.766438  1.053904
1  1.123729  0.373583  0.298866  1.187121  1.485988
2  1.773574  0.120433  0.363052  0.269104  0.632157
3  1.717708  0.330670  1.015575  1.390325  2.405900
4  0.841748  0.181788  0.219881  0.267149  0.487030

In [10]: %timeit -n 100 for col in copy_columns: df_1[col][sample_ind] = df_1['new'][sample_ind] + df_1[col][sample_ind]
100 loops, best of 3: 907 µs per loop

In [11]: %timeit -n 100 df_1.loc[sample_ind, copy_columns] = df_1.loc[sample_ind, 'new'] + df_1.loc[sample_ind, copy_columns]
100 loops, best of 3: 1.12 s per loop
```

So what I'm looking to do is add column 'd' value to column 'a' and 'b' for a given set of ids.  In this example I did it for all of the data.

```
id  a   b   c   d
2   1   2   4   1
3   1   2   3   2
3   1   2   2   2
4   1   2   1   4



id  a   b   c   d
2   2   3   4   1
3   3   4   3   2
3   3   4   2   2
4   5   6   1   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

11 will reconstruct the columns in a safe manner which allows multiple dtype assignments.

10 *will* work only for a single dtype (as you have here); the caveat is [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

The reason 10 is faster than 11 is that 11 makes a copy of the data to work on then swaps it back; 11 direct replaces the values in-place.

For what you are doing its prob ok.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I'm not sure the two approaches will even produce the same output.

Comment: @DSM right as usual! not sure exactly what 10 actually does

Comment: It seems you are correct.  I test out the copy of two identical DataFrame and either of the lines 10 or 11 added the 'new' column to columns 'a' and 'b' which is what I was hoping for.  With this in mind I still need a fast way to add one column value to multiple columns.

Comment: Can you give an example input/output of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'll add a example to the questions in a few minutes

Comment: Example added at the end of the question

Comment: just do it directly: ``df['new_column'] = df.loc[sample_ind,'c'] + df.loc[sample_ind,'d']``; this will be very fast. You only need to use ``loc`` on the lhs if you are overwriting part of an existing column. If you are doign that, then even better is to just construct the rhs as you need it an assign.